# Dynamic source for JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am currently working on a interface which requires an autocomplete of locations.

The list of locations is currently obtained via an AJAX call to a JSON object which is generated dymanically from a URL which has a search parameter of at least three characters.

Is there a way (im guessing most likely using an on key up), to populate the autocomplete by making an ajax call using the input current value and then returning these values in the autocomplete selection, rather than relying on jquery to create the autocomplete list from its source.

What I have currently appears to be inefficient and doesn't work as you might expect (for some reason the autocomplete only appears after four characters).

```
               function buildAutoComplete(fieldId) {

                var inputValue = $("#" + fieldId).val()

                var resultsList = []

                if(inputValue.length > 2) {
                    get("/location?prefix=" + inputValue,inputHit,inputMiss);
                }

                function inputHit(result) {

                    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                        resultsList[i] = result[i].display_text
                    }
                    $("#" + fieldId).autocomplete({
                        source: resultsList
                    });
                }

                function inputMiss() {

                }
            }

            $("#originField").keyup(function() {
                buildAutoComplete("originField");
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was going about this completely the wrong way.

The autocomplete API which I knew allowed a remote source automatically includes a URL parameter of term, of the input value.

So the resulting code looks like

```
$("#originField").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: "/location"
});
```

All it needed was the code at the back of the source to look for the parameter 'term' rather than 'prefix'.

Considerably more stable with a less complex and smaller code base.